# Store friend request after accept ( In Database )

Tags: python, django, database, django-admin

I am building a Social Media App and I am trying to store friend requests in Database after accept or Reject.

**What i am trying to do :-**

When `user_1` send friend request to `user_2` then in Admin it stores `sent or received friend requests` until accept or Reject. AND after accept or Reject it deleted from the DataBase. BUT i want to store requests permanently. So i can see all the requests sent or received by `request.user`.

models.py

```
class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='to_user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='from_user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def send_friend_request(request,user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User,id=user_id)
    frequest, created = FriendRequest.objects.get_or_create(from_user=request.user,to_user=user)
    return redirect('friends',user_id=user_id)



def accept_friend_request(request,user_id):
    user1 = frequest.to_user
    user2 = from_user
    from_user = get_object_or_404(User,id=user_id)
    frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=from_user,to_user=request.user).first()

    user1.profile.friends.add(user2.profile)
    user2.profile.friends.add(user1.profile)
    if(FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user,to_user=from_user).first()):
        request_rev = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user,to_user=from_user).first()
        request_rev.delete()
    frequest.delete()
    return redirect('friends',user_id=user_id)
```

**What have i tried :-**

I have also tried by adding another instance in `FriendRequest Model` BUT it is not saving in the Admin.

I have no idea, How can i do it.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store friend requests permanently, you can add a new field to the FriendRequest model. The new field can store the status of the friend request. You can give it a default value of 'pending' or 'sent' or 'received', since when a friend request is sent, it is in pending state. If the friend request is accepted, you can update the status of the friend request to 'accepted', or if it is rejected, you can update its status to 'rejected'.

Your `models.py` would now look like:

```
class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='to_user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='from_user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    PENDING = 'p'
    ACCEPTED = 'a'
    REJECTED = 'r'

    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (ACCEPTED, 'Accepted'),
        (REJECTED, 'Rejected')
    ]

    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=PENDING)
```

If your FriendRequests model is registered with admin, it will show up on admin as well.

In your `accept_friend_request` view, instead of deleting the friend request entry from the database, you can simply update its status to 'a' i.e. 'Accepted'.